# Is there any effect that draws the oscillation frequencies of two particles together?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators

I'm looking for any sort of coupling that draws oscillation amplitudes together if one couples two (nearly) harmonic oscillators, basically the opposite of [avoided crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoided_crossing)  or level repulsion.

Is this possible?